# pseudo- element ::selection doesn't work on the first letter if i use ::first-letter. CSS

Tags: css, selection

After using p::first-letter I cant make p::selection, because it works only to other letters, not including first.[picture of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmg0n.png). How can I gat access to the selection of first letter?

I've tried to do smth like this: p::first-letter::selection{}, but as we know we can't use more than one pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are right and there is no way of chaining pseudo elements. As far as I know the only way to achieve what you are trying to do is by wrapping the first letter in a `<span>` or similar and put the styling onto there.

If your content comes from a CMS or similar you'll probably also need some JavaScript to dynamically render it around the first letter.

```css
span {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

::selection {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
 <span>H</span>ello
</p>
```